# Using nested formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on problem that necessitates the use of nested formulas in excel. For eg:

I have a column for errors and one for its analysis

```
       Error                            Analysis
Enter a valid material number       Invalid Material
```

Eg errors:

1. Enter a valid material number; The material number 1234 does not
   exist.
2. PO number XYZ does not exist.
3. VIN number 123 does not exist.
4. Country of origin AB does not exist.

I have a compendium of such errors and their analyis in the next sheet, and I'm using VLOOKUP in conjuction with FIND to lookup the analysis for the known errors.

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2, FIND(" ", F2, FIND(" ", F2) + 1) - 1)&"*", 'Sheet2'!A:B, 2, 0)
```

What i'm trying to do here is extract the first two words from the error and append a * to it and use it in VLOOKUP.

It would be something like Vlookup "PO number *" in the other sheet and get the analysis for it. Asterisk is because I don 't get the same number daily. And I also know that the extracted first two words of the error will be unique. (I know that error with "Enter a" as the first two words will not appear again).

Now I get errors in the same column so I thought of making a button and writing a code which uses the above formula.

I tried to modify some code off the net, but I'm not getting anywhere with it. I'm  totally new to VBA. It'd be great if you can provide a snippet for this. I'll try to replicate the procedure for other needs.

*This code seems to be working for now*

```
Sub PopulateAnalysis()
Dim an_row As Long
Dim an_clm As Long
Dim lft As String
Dim st_num As Integer
Dim fin As String
Dim searchStr As String
Dim soughtStr As String
Table1 = Sheet1.Range("F2:F6") 'ErrorColumn from Error table (How do I make the range dynamic??)
Table2 = Sheet5.Range("A1:B6")
an_row = Sheet1.Range("G2").Row ' Populate this column from the analysis table on sheet2
an_clm = Sheet1.Range("G2").Column
For Each cl In Table1
   'How do I translate the above formula into VBA statements??

  st_num = InStr(InStr(cl, " ") + 1, cl, " ")
  lft = left(cl, st_num - 1)
  fin = lft & "*"
  Sheet1.Cells(an_row, an_clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(fin, Table2, 2, True)
  an_row = an_row + 1
Next cl

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you just use Vlookup? I don't understand the formula you provided, what are you trying to extract? If the `Error` and the `Analysis` records are paired, you can use vlookup, exact match.

Comment: Add some data to your question that produces the errors. Also, show the code you've generated and point out where you feel you've gone off track.

Comment: NOTE: it can be fake data that reproduces the issue if the information is sensitive.

Comment: @BranislavKollár- The above formula works perfectly when I use it in a cell. The formula extracts the first two words and appends a " * " and VLOOKUP looks it up in other sheet where the recurring errors and their analysis maintained. The reason I'm extracting first two words is because of a variable component such as a number that may appear in the middle of the error text. For eg, Enter a valid material number; Material number 1234 doesn't exist.  Another eg would be- VIN number 23454 is invalid. The first words are the most I can use it as a common text and look it up in the other table.

Comment: @BranislavKollár There's not a lot of variety in errors. Hence the above approach works. Now, this sheet is not for me and the people who would want to use it may not understand or want to type it daily. Hence the need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You don't need the debug lines of course ;)

```
Sub PopulateAnalysis()

    Dim rngTableWithErrors As Range
    Dim rngTableWithAnalysis As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'set the range for Table with error, Table1 on sheet 1
    With Sheets(1) 'change to name of the sheet, more reliable than index num.
        Set rngTableWithErrors = .Range("F2:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row)
        Debug.Print rngTableWithErrors.Address
    End With

    'set the range for Table with Analysis, Table 2 on sheet 2
    With Sheets(2) 'change to name of the sheet, more reliable than index num.
        Set rngTableWithAnalysis = .Range("A1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
        Debug.Print rngTableWithAnalysis.Address
    End With

    'formula for cell G2
    '=VLOOKUP(LEFT(F2;FIND(" ";F2;FIND(" ";F2)+1)- 1)&"*";Sheet2!A1:B23;2; 0)
    rngTableWithErrors.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(LEFT(R[0]C[-1],FIND("" "",R[0]C[-1],FIND("" "",R[0]C[-1])+1)-1)& ""*"",Sheet2!R1C1:R" & rngTableWithAnalysis.Rows.Count & "C2,2, 0)"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

---

## Notes

You can notice, that we are setting the upper left cells of ranges manually. It's better practice to somehow find the upper left cells (using `Find method` is my favorite) and work from there. You never know, how the user will change the worksheet - i.e. add new rows, columns etc.

Comment: Then please, be so kind, and accept the anwer. Thank you, glad to be of help.

Comment: There's a small niggle though; As I was testing this, I found that the "rngTableWithAnalysis.Rows.Count" doesn't actually take into account the latest addition of rows to the table. It still takes the value it acquired when it ran the first time. Is there a way around this?

Comment: That can happen, if the added records are blank in column B. Since we are determining the last row in this column, by finding last filled cell in this column. Is this the case? Are there some blank cells in column B? Especially at the bottom of the range.

Comment: Nope that's not the case. There are no blank cells. However, I observed that it's not counting the header.I deleted some rows. It's taking  one less than the actual number of rows. Guess it doesn't count the header.

Comment: If you deleted some rows, you need to *amend the manualy set ranges* (the upper left most cells I talked about in the notes). A problem can be here : `...rngTableWithErrors = .Range("F2:F"...` (change the 2) or here `...rngTableWithAnalysis = .Range("A1:B"...` (change the 1) or here `...Sheet2!R1C1:R" & rngTableWithAnalysis.Rows.Count &...` (change the R1).